# Rails Upgrade 3.2 to 4.0: Model deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-3-upgrade

In Rails 3.2, I have a user Model as follows->

```
User model

has_many :billing_invoices, :through => :user_purchases, :select => "DISTINCT billing_invoices.invoice_date,billing_invoices.account_number"
```

I am trying to upgrade to Rails 4.0 and I get the Deprecation warning to use a scope block instead. 
How can I rewrite this has_many statement to work in 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon this is what you need:

`has_many :billing_invoices, -> { distinct }, through: :user_purchases`

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-distinct

**Updated:**

If you want to override `SELECT` then:

`has_many :billing_invoices, -> { select("DISTINCT billing_invoices.invoice_date,billing_invoices.account_number") }, :through => :user_purchases`

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-select

Comment: Thanks! How can I tweak this for multiple distinct values?

Comment: I am trying has_many :billing_invoices, -> { select  "DISTINCT billing_invoices.invoice_date,billing_invoices.account_number"}, :through => :user_purchases